# Fire Assignment rule for Case via apex

Tags: apex

I want to fire Assignment rule for case but it's not possible via quick action( I have to used quick action)

So is there any way I can fire Assignment rule on trigger for case.

```
//Fetching the assignment rules on case
AssignmentRule AR = new AssignmentRule();
AR = [select id from AssignmentRule where SobjectType = 'Case' and Active = true limit 1];

//Creating the DMLOptions for "Assign using active assignment rules" checkbox
Database.DMLOptions dmlOpts = new Database.DMLOptions();
dmlOpts.assignmentRuleHeader.assignmentRuleId= AR.id;
System.debug('dmlOpts :: '+dmlOpts);

Case newCase = new Case(Status = 'New',No_of_Employees__c = 5) ;
//Setting the DMLOption on Case instance
newCase.setOptions(dmlOpts);
insert newCase ;
System.debug('newCase :: '+newCase);
```

Comment: Yes, Here it is: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000338182&type=1&mode=1

Comment: also, [appexchange product](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000ErILmUAN) (free)

Comment: Hi Arnold, I have tried the given link before also and try now also but by some how it wont work. I also update my code to check you guys out let me know if any update on it

Comment: @ParthNaik If you're having a problem with this code, please [edit] to be specific about *exactly* what behavior you see versus what you expect.

Comment: Code worked perfectly but case assignment rule won't triggered.